# How to delete a character from a string using java

Tags: java, string, substring

I am trying to delete character at a time from a string in Java this is what I wrote

```
String word = "evelina";
char[] wordCharArr = word.toCharArray();

//Deleting one

for(int i = 0; i< wordCharArr.length; i++)
{
    String answer = word.subString(i);
    if(list.lookup(answer))
        perm.add(answer);
}
```

What this does is this:

```
evelina
velina
elina
lina
ina
na
a
```

But I need it to do this

```
evelina
velina
eelina
evlina
eveina
evelna
evelia
evelin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At each iteration, you need to skip the `i-th` character:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordCharArr.length; i++) {
  String answer = word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1);
  if (list.lookup(answer)) {
    perm.add(answer);
  }
}
```